# Average over number of variables where number of variables is dictated by separate column

Tags: sas

I would like to create a new column whose values equal the average of values in other columns. But the number of columns I am taking the average of is dictated by a variable. My data look like this, with 'length' dictating the number of columns x1-x5 that I want to average:

```
data have;
    input ID $ length x1 x2 x3 x4 x5;
    datalines;
A 5 8 234 79 36 78
B 4 8 26 589 3 54
C 3 19 892 764 89 43
D 5 72 48 65 4 9
;
run;
```

I would like to end up with the below where 'avg' is the average of the specified columns.

```
data want;
    input ID $ length avg
    datalines;
A 5 87
B 4 156.5
C 3 558.3
D 5 39.6
;
run;
```

Any suggestions? Thanks! Sorry about the awful title, I did my best.

Comment: avg=mean(of x1-x5)

Comment: @crow16384 I don't want all rows to take the average of x1-x5. Row B should only take the average of x1-x4 and row C should only take the average of x1-x3. Lmk if I can make this clearer in my post.

Comment: Ok. I see. Use arrays. Will try to show in answer

Comment: Are missing values possible and if so, how should they be handled? Should the denominator be Length or Length - number of missing?

Comment: @Reeza no missing values possible here. Stu's solution worked great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do a little more work since `mean(of x[1]-x[length])` is not valid syntax. Instead, save the values to a temporary array and take the mean of it, then reset it at each row. For example:

```
tmp1 tmp2 tmp3 tmp4 tmp5
8    234  79   36   78
8    26   589  3    .
19   892  764  .    . 
72   48   65   4    9

data want;
    set have;
    array x[*] x:;
    array tmp[5] _temporary_;
    
    /* Reset the temp array */
    call missing(of tmp[*]);

    /* Save each value of x to the temp array */
    do i = 1 to length;
        tmp[i] = x[i];
    end;

    /* Get the average of the non-missing values in the temp array */
    avg = mean(of tmp[*]);

    drop i;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Reeza's solution is good, but in case of missing values in x it will produce not always desirable result. It's better to use a function **SUM**. Also the code is little simplified:

```
data want (drop=i s);
  set have;
  array a{*} x:;
  s=0; nm=0;
  do i=1 to length;
    if missing(a{i}) then nm+1;
    s=sum(s,a{i});
  end;
  avg=s/(length-nm);
run;
```

Comment: It needs to be a touch more complex than this unfortunately.

Comment: @Reeza, I have changed my solution basing on yours. My was incorrect.

Comment: Good catch on missing values. OP would need to clarify if that's an issue, and if so how it would be handled. The other solutions would change the denominator but yours would basically consider it as 0.

Comment: @Reeza, Yes, you are right! A denominator should be also corrected in case of missing. I have missed that. The solution is corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array to average it by summing up the array for the length and then dividing by the length.

```
data have;
    input ID $ length x1 x2 x3 x4 x5;
datalines;
A 5 8 234 79 36 78
B 4 8 26 589 3 54
C 3 19 892 764 89 43
D 5 72 48 65 4 9
;

data want;
set have;

array x(5) x1-x5;

sum=0;

do i=1 to length;
    sum + x(i);
end;

avg = sum/length;

keep id length avg;
format avg 8.2;

run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing your own code to calculate means you could just calculate all of the possible means and then just use an index into an array to select the one you need.

```
data have;
    input ID $ length x1 x2 x3 x4 x5;
datalines;
A 5 8 234 79 36 78
B 4 8 26 589 3 54
C 3 19 892 764 89 43
D 5 72 48 65 4 9
;

data want;
  set have;
  array means[5] ;
  means[1]=x1;
  means[2]=mean(x1,x2);
  means[3]=mean(of x1-x3);
  means[4]=mean(of x1-x4);
  means[5]=mean(of x1-x5);
  want = means[length];
run;
```

Results:
[image]